# accessing my node.js REST with angularjs

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, node.js

I have working angular code with local json file like this

```
App.controller('bodyController', ['$scope','$http',function($scope,$http){
$http.get('data.json').success(function(data){
    $scope.data=data;

}).error(function(){

});
```

}]);
but for a working api that returns json on the browser it doesn't seem to work

```
App.controller('bodyController', ['$scope','$http',function($scope,$http){
$http.get('http://localhost:8090/api/all').success(function(data){
    $scope.data=data;

}).error(function(){

});
```

}]);
url based on node server returns exactly like data.json content http://localhost:8090/api/all

I have checked chrome's cross origin thing that is not the case here 
am using firefox,with the output console stating ok get response
[image]

Comment: Your picture includes an error message that you've covered up with a window. It might be relevant.

Comment: try to use data.data as response send as {data: {}}

Comment: I have fixed that error now ,it was not successfully getting the data from http and so goes to error function. Now i want to know why it wasn't successful

Comment: that is how it is formatted,orginally I am giving thesame json locally and its reading it .I think the problem is accessing the api which works for me on the browser

Answer (score 0):

This problem happened because I was running my home html page manually but after configuring my app to use static assets as follows,I was able to call and route the API directly from angular.

1. here I configured my html home page using express static on

> http://expressjs.com/starter/static-files.html

2. Now I can access my page as static asset so the api works fine since it is called from the server that hosted it.

   $http.get('/api/all')